# Why does Postgres choose different data solely based on columns selected?

Tags: postgresql, sum, union, union-all

I'm running two different queries with two unions each inside a subquery:

[image: Both queries]

So the structure is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (subquery_1
UNION SELECT subquery_2)
```

Now, if I perform the query on the left, I get this result:
[image: Query #1 Result]

However, the query on the right returns this result:
[image: Query #2 Result]

How are the results differing even though the conditions have not changed in either query, and the only difference was one of the selected columns in a subquery?

This is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Though I generally agree with @a_horse_with_no_name about the images in questions, the 1st image in this question which presents the 2 queries side by side by highlighting their differences, is the best way to describe the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator [`UNION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) removes duplicate rows from the returned resultset.

Removing a column from the `SELECT` statement may produce duplicate rows that would not exist if the removed column was there.

Try `UNION ALL` instead, which will return in any case all the rows of the unioned queries.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=94c510f249a7d66f6ba97c1e5921a315).